# Page resolution of the printed version of a document printed from a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, telerik, richtextbox

I have a `RadRichTextBox` that have a `RadDocument` loaded. This is then used to print mentioned document using `richTextBox.Print()`.

The main problem is that the resolution of the printed page is tied to the zoom of the document in the viewer (RadRichTextBox), i.e. if I have the document zoomed way out (small pages on screen) the resolution on the printed paper is terrible. On the other hand, if I zoom in, the resolution becomes really good.

Obviously, I want to always print at the best possible resolution, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Work-around that seem to work is saving the scale factor, setting it to 10,10 then restoring the original: `Size sf = richTextBox.ScaleFactor; richTextBox.ScaleFactor = new Size(10,10); richTextBox.Print(settings); richTextBox.ScaleFactor = sf;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with a work around that works by saving the scaling, setting it to a high number, then restoring it after printing the document.

```
Size sf = richTextBox.ScaleFactor; 
richTextBox.ScaleFactor = new Size(10,10); 
richTextBox.Print(/*... settings ...*/); 
richTextBox.ScaleFactor = sf;
```

This looks weird, as the documents zooms in while the document is printing, but the printed document have a proper resolution.